# Can I use 'could not' to talk about negative possibilities?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

In this video (at 3:43) some guy told me that I can't use 'could' to talk about negative possibilities. Is it true? If so, why?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMGxeChtYLc

> They might not be ready.
>
> He may not be able to help you.

The guy said that there is no way to use 'could' in these sentences.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clearer what exactly you’re asking. What is a negative possibility? Please provide an example sentence to show what type of context you’re asking about.

Comment: Could? (with a question mark)...it shows doubt.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: That's a long video. Please say at what time he says that. As native speakers we don't want to listen to the whole thing. Thanks.

Comment: If you use 'could [not]', you automatically get an impossibility (A was not possible), as opposed to a 'negative possibility' (not-A is possible).

Comment: He says that at 3:43

Comment: @Keep these mind Thanks. This is actually an answer

Comment: If you are going to alter a question in a way that invalidates an already provided answer, please make a note of its original version. Otherwise, existing answers may be taken as wrong.

Comment: No worries. In this case, I was able to address both variations. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: This question was changed *after* I answered it. Originally, it had only been asking about *could*, not *could not*.

---

I see no reason why you can't recast both of those sentences to use *could* while preserving their meaning:

> They might not be ready.
>  They could be unprepared.
>
> He may not be able to help you.
>  He could be unable to help you.

We replace *might not* or *may not* with *could*, and replace the positive statement with a negative statement (*be ready* becomes *be unprepared* and *be able to* becomes *be unable to*).

---

Something similar can also be done with *could not*:

> They might not be ready.
>  They could not necessarily be ready.
>
> He may not be able to help you.
>  He could not necessarily be able to help you.

Here, the last part of the sentence remains in the positive.

Comment: Yes, but if we use exactly "could not" the meaning becomes different, doesn't it?

Comment: @OleksiyPlotnyts'kyy See my updated answer.

Comment: The example that comes to mind for me is an exchange of this kind: "I could do <some ill-advised thing>" followed by "Or you could not do <ill-advised thing>." If spoken, the "not" would be emphasized.